# Get post content inside plugin class method

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, actions, oop

I'm writing a simple SEO class that will add the various metatag to the header of wordpress. 
I've two little problems with the wordpress api. 
The first is that I need to remove the last comma from the tag list, I've tried with `rtrim` but without success. 
The secont problem is that I'm unable to load the content of the post or page to create the content of the description meta tag. How I can fix these two issues?

```
<?php

/*
* Plugin Name: Custom Meta Tag
*/

class WP_Custom_Meta_Tag{

  private $post_tags;
  private $key;
  private $keyword;
  private $description;

  public function init(){
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_meta_description'));
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_meta_keywords'));
  }

  /*
  * metatag keywords
  */
  public function add_meta_keywords(){
    if( is_single() ){
      $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
      $key = '';
      foreach( $post_tags as $keyword ){
        $key .= $keyword->name.', ';
      }
      echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$key.'">';
    }

  }

  /*
  * metatag description
  */
  public function add_meta_description(){
    if( is_single() ){

      #$description = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
      $d = get_the_content( $post->ID );
      #$description = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
      #$description = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $description );
      #$description = substr( $description, 0, 125 );

      #echo '<meta name="description" content="'. $description .'">';
      var_dump($d);
    }
  }

}

$meta = new WP_Custom_Meta_Tag;
$meta->init();
?>
```

**EDIT**

I've fixed the issue, and now all seems to work correctly. If anyone has a suggestion to better trim the description text, please share an answer. I've read about `wp_trim_words`, but it will not work. 
Here is the updated code:

```
class WP_Custom_Meta_Tag{

  private $post_tags;
  private $key;
  private $keyword;
  private $description;

  public function init(){
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_metatags'), 1);
  }

  /*
  * metatag keywords
  */
  public function add_metatags(){
    global $post;
    if( is_single() || is_page() ){
      $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
      $key = [];
      foreach( $post_tags as $keyword ){
        $key[] = $keyword->name;
      }
      // this part needs to be improved
      $description = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
      $description = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
      $description = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $description );
      $description = substr( $description, 0, 140 );

      echo '<meta name="description" content="'. $description .'" />';
      echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.implode(',' ,$key).'" />';
      echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'. get_the_title( $post->ID ) .'" />';
      echo '<meta property="og:description" content="'. $description .'"/>';
      #echo '<meta property="og:type" content="" />';
      echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'. get_the_permalink( $post->ID ) .'" />';
      if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID , 'full') .'" />';
      }
    }
  }

}

$meta = new WP_Custom_Meta_Tag;
$meta->init();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove the last comma from the tag list

Put all `$keyword->name` into an array and use `implode()` to get the result.

> I'm unable to load the content of the post or page

Object `$post` is not available in your function. Use `global $post;` to access `$post->ID` and `$post->post_content` etc.

So,

```
public function add_meta_keywords(){
    if( is_single() ){
      $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
      $key = '';
      foreach( $post_tags as $keyword ){
        $key .= $keyword->name.', ';
      }
      echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$key.'">';
    }

  }
```

should be something like this

```
public function add_meta_keywords(){
    if( is_single() ){

      global $post;

      $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
      $key = array();
      foreach( $post_tags as $keyword ){
        $key []= $keyword->name;
      }
      echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.implode(', ',$key).'">';
    }

  }
```

And

```
public function add_meta_description(){
    if( is_single() ){

      #$description = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
      $d = get_the_content( $post->ID );
      #$description = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
      #$description = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $description );
      #$description = substr( $description, 0, 125 );

      #echo '<meta name="description" content="'. $description .'">';
      var_dump($d);
    }
  }
```

should be

```
public function add_meta_description(){

    global $post;

    if( is_single() ){
      global $post;

      #$description = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
      $d = get_the_content( $post->ID );
      #$description = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
      #$description = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $description );
      #$description = substr( $description, 0, 125 );

      #echo '<meta name="description" content="'. $description .'">';
      var_dump($d);
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

> Better solution to trim the description to 140 characters.

TRY this

```
// Checks the content's length, if more 140 chars...
// Output  140 chars, but don't break a word

if ( strlen($description) > 140){

    $description = substr($description, 0, strpos($description, ' ', 140));
}

echo '<meta name="description" content="'. $description .'">';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will try and let you know.

Comment: If I want to assign to the `add_action` the execution priority, how I can do this? I've tried in the standard way, but the consolle will notify me an error, so I cant write the syntax `add_action('wp_head', 'my_function', 1)`

Comment: @ZWPDev for priority issue, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684371/11103484) may help. BTW what console error do yo get?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members` I will look the answer, to try fix also this issue. I'm facing also a problem if I try to echo some og tags.

Comment: It seems you used     `add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_meta_description', 1));` instead of  ` add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'add_meta_description'), 1);`

Comment: Yes, I was writing in that way the function, but I will fix it as suggested. Any Idea about the og tag that aren't echoed?

Comment: I need that the tags are positioned at the top ho the wp header. Unfortunately, if I set the priority of 1, they are doubled. The og tags instead are placed inside the body. I've messed up with the code.

Comment: For og tag, share your code, either by updating your question or creating a new question.

Comment: I've fixed for the og tags, the `wp_head()` was duplied inside the theme header, but I've updated the code, I want to use a better solution to trim the description to 140 charatcers.

Comment: @ZWPDev check updated answer for trimmed description.

Comment: @ZWPDev Oh, my mistake, I have edited the answer. Let me know if it resolve the issue...

Comment: I will try your suggestion about the trim. I need to go deeper with the wordpress API documentation, I use it only for small project in alternative to laravel or custom php oop code. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know.